# How to pass a date (year) parameter to my url?

Tags: django, django-templates

This is a huge rookie mistake but I can't figure it out.

This is what I wanna do:

I have a page displaying a list a years where an objects is available.
I want that, when I click on a year, it takes me to the corresponding YearArchiveView. I just don't succeed in passing the right parameter to the URL. Passing a template tag obviously doesnt work so what is the right way to do it ?

I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /receipts/
Could not parse some characters: |{{y||date:"Y"}}
```

My template:

```
  <ul>
    {% for y in years_available %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'receipt_year_archive' year={{y|date:"Y"}} %}">{{y|date:"Y"}}</a></li>
    {% empty %}
       <p>No Receipt Yet</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

My view:

```
class ReceiptListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Receipt
    template_name = 'receipts.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Receipt.objects.dates('date_created','year',order="DESC")
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReceiptListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['years_available'] = Receipt.objects.dates('date_created',
                'year', order="DESC")
        return context
```

My urls.py:

```
 url(r'receipts/(?P<year>[0-9]{4}/$)',views.ReceiptYearArchiveView.as_view(),
    name='receipt_year_archive'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need year=

just use this

```
    <ul>
        {% for y in years_available %}
{% with y|date:"Y" as current_year %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'receipt_year_archive' current_year  %}">{{y|date:"Y"}}</a></li>
{% endwith %}
        {% empty %}
           <p>No Receipt Yet</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

Comment: I tried this too already but it raises the same exceptions: Could not parse some characters: |{{y||date:"Y"}}

Comment: `{% y|date:"Y" as current_year %}` is invalid. I think you meant to use the `with` tag.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair and Exprator, the correct answer is:

`<ul>
    {% for y in years_available %}
 {% with y|date:"Y" as current_year %}
 <li><a href="{% url 'receipt_year_archive' current_year %}">{{y|date:"Y"}}</a></li>
 {% endwith %}
    {% empty %}
    <p>No Receipt Yet</p>
{% endfor %}</ul>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't add another `{{` and `}}` inside `{%`. It should call with direct variable.

```
<ul>
  {% for y in years_available %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'receipt_year_archive' y|date:'Y' %}">{{ y|date:"Y" }}</a></li>
  {% empty %}
    <p>No Receipt Yet</p>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

*But,* I think your case similiar with [this docs examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#examples):

```
<ul>
  {% for yearvar in year_list %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'news-year-archive' yearvar %}">{{ yearvar }} Archive</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

> If the output of `years_available` is a list of integer years.
>   eg: [1992, 2001, 2005, 2011, 2014] 
>   It should be:

```
<ul>
  {% for y in years_available %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'receipt_year_archive' y %}">{{ y }}</a></li>
  {% empty %}
    <p>No Receipt Yet</p>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: years_available is a queryset containing datetime objects so it's not a list of integers

Comment: It should have work according to the docs yes, but wasn't for me